# How can I make IMGs width independent of parent's width?

Tags: php, html, css, image

I have an `<a class='col-span-6 h-[36rem] flex overflow-x-scroll'>` tag in which I load all images in a directory dynamically using PHP. Below you can see what I mean and what the problem is. Since the `<a>` tag has overflow on it set, why can't the image's width go beyond it's parent's width? Why must it squish? I've tried what must now be a million combinations of `w-full, h-full, object-cover, object-none, object-contain` on the `<a>` tag itself, on parent divs, etc. It's driving me insane and my brain is foggy. Obviously I've tried googling and searching stackoverflow but I can't find anything.

Dynamic PHP code inside `<a>`:

```
function imgLoad($dirPath, $index){
    $dir = ($dirPath . scandir($dirPath)[$index]);
    $files = scandir($dir);
    foreach($files as $file) {
        if($file !== "." && $file !== ".." && $file !== "info.php") {
            echo "<img src='$dir/$file' class='lg:h-full object-cover' loading='lazy' />";
        }
    }
}
```

This is the compiled PHP code:

```
<img src="folder/folder/folder/folder/img.jpg" class="lg:h-full" loading="lazy">
```

Parent div:

```
<div class="pl-24 mb-32 grid grid-cols-8"></div>
```

Which looks like this:
[image]

Until:
[image]

Comment: Can you add some code of what you have tried for placing the image?
I mean compiled code by PHP. You can get it from browsers developers' tools.

Comment: @BharathAsl Added!